# Howto clone/copy/mirror a jquery tab

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, tabs, jquery-ui-tabs, jquery-tabs

How can i make jquery tabs, with exactly the same tabs
on top AND bottom of the content?

So these 2 tabs combined, and MIRRORing eachother:

http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/default.html

http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/bottom.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a total hack of jQuery tabs, but I couldn't think of any other way to to this easily.
You only have to put the style on the cloned tabs. You can check out a live example [here](http://dev.bogdanconstantinescu.com/stackoverflow/jquerytabs.html).

The `hacked` JavaScript code is as follows:

```
$(function() {

        var myTabs = $("#tabs").tabs();
        var x = $('.ui-tabs-nav').clone().addClass('mySecondTabs');
        $('#tabs').append(x);
        $('.mySecondTabs').tabs();

        $('#tabs').tabs({

            select: function(event, ui) 
            {  
                index = ui.index;
                x = $('.mySecondTabs').children('li:nth-child('+(parseInt(index)+1)+')');
                $('.mySecondTabs').children('li').removeClass('ui-tabs-selected').removeClass('ui-state-active');
                x.addClass('ui-tabs-selected').addClass('ui-state-active');
            }
        });

        $('.mySecondTabs').children('li').click(function () 
        {
            $('#tabs').tabs("select", $('.mySecondTabs').children('li').index(this));
        });


    });
```

Comment: The linked page doesn't work any more (it references http://www.jqueryui.com/jquery-1.4.2.js which no longer exists)

Answer (score 0):

It`s very simple:

```
$('#tabs').tabs();    
$('#my-text-link').click(function(){
   $('#tabs').tabs( "option", "active", 1 ); //open the second tab [0,1,2...]
});
```